# Perl - change lines to comma separated vars

Tags: perl

I want to do this from command line on Mac. So, I guess that Perl could be option for it but I don't have idea how to do it:

I have one file with 100,000 names
one name per line

I want to change it and to have 50 names in one line separated by comma
then next line with next 50 names separated by comma, etc..

Comment: You have to try something. You can't post 'specs' and expect code back.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following one-liner:

```
perl -pe 's/\n/,/ if $. % 50' < file > output
```

It replaces the newline (`\n`) with a comma if the current input line number (`$.`) is not divisible (`%`) by 50.

Comment: But how to write it another file ?

Comment: I have try this: perl -pe 's/\n/,/ if $. % 50' old.txt > new.txt
But it wrote all names in one line, not 50 per line

Comment: @user1070318: Weird. Works for me.

Comment: He is using mac, perhaps he has a weird line ending. Use `s/\s+\z/,/` instead.